# How to disable anchor tag pressed

Tags: jquery

How to disable an anchor tag when pressed with jQuery?   I tried `e.preventDefault();` but that disabled all the anchor tags and not the one pressed.

```
 $(".header_menu .header_menu_res ul > .menu-item a, .content_res .header_menu_res ul > .menu-item a").live("click",function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).find(".adv_categories").length==1) {
            if($(this).find('.adv_categories').hasClass("importantRule")) {
                $(this).find('.adv_categories').removeClass("importantRule");
                $(this).removeClass("importantRuleButton");
            } else {
                if($(this).siblings(".menu-item").find(".sub-menu").hasClass("importantRule")) {
                    $(this).siblings(".menu-item").find(".sub-menu").removeClass("importantRule");
                }
                $(this).find('.adv_categories').addClass("importantRule");
                $(this).addClass("importantRuleButton");
            }
        } 
    });
```

Here is the html of the li

```
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a class="primary" href="http://www.test.co.uk/about-us/"><em class="icon-info"></em>About Us</a>
<ul class="adv_categories"><li></li></ul></li>
```

What happens is the page still goes to `about-us`.  I want it to be disabled.  When I used `e.preventDefault();` the `sub-menu` showed.

Comment: can i have an example please?

Comment: If it is doing it for all anchor tags, and not the single one you want, then you need to be more specific in your selector.

Comment: check edit i made more specific and still same result.

Comment: I'm afraid that the wording of this question plus the comments posted in the suggested answer seem to point to this being an unclear question.  I'd suggest rephrasing the question and thinking about adding additional clarity to help the responders better understand what it is that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you register a handler for a click on the anchor and when the function associated with the handler is invoked, it is passed the event as a parameter.  One can then ask that event to stop being propagated and the result will be no default handling for the anchor which would be navigation.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myA").click(function(e) {
    alert("Clicked");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="myA" href="http://www.ibm.com">Go to IBM</a>
```

Comment: is `.click` for the specific anchor clicked?  I used `.live("click")`?

Comment: In jQuery, one can specify a "selector" which is used to determine a set of elements.  The result of the selector can then have other modifications applied.  In the example I provided, it says "Find the element with id of "myA" and add a click handler to it".  The selector can be changed to use classes, ids, element types and more to select whatever you want to apply the handler to.

Comment: I know this but what if they have all the same class.  I want `$(this)` anchor to be disabled.

Comment: @user892134 I don't think I'm following your question.  From the subject line and description, I had thought that what you wanted was to disable the default action of an anchor tag click.  The answer has illustrated that.  Can you clarify what the answer omits and maybe update the question to make it clear what else is being asked?

Comment: For example, if 5 buttons each have the class `one`.  I want to disable the 1 button pressed not all of 5 of them. That is the problem i'm having.